# Looping through multiple folders to calculate mean(s) of multiple rasters using cell statistcs ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, modis, cell-statistics, land-surface-temperature

I am a novice in Python programing.
I have multiple MODIS rasters in different folders for which I want to calculate the mean of corresponding rasters in each folder. I have tried the following code:

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

## Creating mean of daytime and nighttime LST for Terra data
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/MSc_GIS_UoA/3rd_Session_Dissertation/Data/MODIS/Study_Period/Terra_Day/"

Terra_Day = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")

arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/MSc_GIS_UoA/3rd_Session_Dissertation/Data/MODIS/Study_Period/Terra_Night/"

Terra_Night = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")

os.mkdir("E:/MSc_GIS_UoA/3rd_Session_Dissertation/Data/MODIS/Study_Period/Terra_Mean/") #Creating a new folder to save the output

arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/MSc_GIS_UoA/3rd_Session_Dissertation/Data/MODIS/Study_Period/Terra_Mean/"

for (a,b) in zip(Terra_Day,Terra_Night):
    outCellStats = CellStatistics([f"E:/MSc_GIS_UoA/3rd_Session_Dissertation/Data/MODIS/Study_Period/Terra_Day/{a}", f"E:/MSc_GIS_UoA/3rd_Session_Dissertation/Data/MODIS/Study_Period/Terra_Night/{b}"],"MEAN", "NODATA") #Using a and b as variables for the filenames of the rasters in each folder

outCellStats.save(f"E:/MSc_GIS_UoA/3rd_Session_Dissertation/Data/MODIS/Study_Period/Terra_Mean/{a}")
```

The code works perfectly when run. The problem, however, is that the output is a single raster having the same name as the last raster name in both folders. I understand I have to have as many outputs (911 rasters) for the mean as I have for the inputs.

Comment: Are you sure they are listed in the correct order so you compare the same day (if that is what you are doing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only saving once, the last result, because you've placed the saving outside the for loop.

Try:

```
...

for a,b in zip(Terra_Day,Terra_Night):
    outCellStats = CellStatistics([f"E:/MSc_GIS_UoA/3rd_Session_Dissertation/Data/MODIS/Study_Period/Terra_Day/{a}", f"E:/MSc_GIS_UoA/3rd_Session_Dissertation/Data/MODIS/Study_Period/Terra_Night/{b}"],"MEAN", "NODATA") #Using a and b as variables for the filenames of the rasters in each folder
    outCellStats.save(f"E:/MSc_GIS_UoA/3rd_Session_Dissertation/Data/MODIS/Study_Period/Terra_Mean/{a}")
```

Then you will save the result for each iteration:

```
c = [2,3]
d = [5,10]

for a,b in zip(c,d):
    result = a*b
    print(f'You should save {result} here')

print(f'\nBut you only save {result} here')

#Output
#You should save 10 here
#You should save 30 here

#But you only save 30 here
```

Comment: I added the .save line to the 'for' loop and it works perfectly now. Thank you.